# FFmpeg/X264: Split video mid-GOP without reencoding entire stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, x264

I've got an H264 video (Stored in an MP4 file). Each GOP is approx 10s long. I want to trim the first couple of seconds off the video, which means I need to split the first GOP. Is there a way to do this without re-encoding the entire video?

I've got FFmpeg and x264 available. I'm happy to use either the FFmpeg command line, or my own program linked against ffmpeg of x264 libraries.

Comment: Does the video contain B pictures?

Comment: appears this question received an answer here, as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545002/ffmpeg-x264-split-video-mid-gop-without-reencoding-entire-stream

Answer (score 1):

FFVhuff is lossless codec

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v ffvhuff FFVhuff.mkv

ffmpeg -ss 26.818 -i FFVhuff.mkv trim.mkv
```

http://svnpenn.blogspot.com/2011/10/ffmpeg-cut-to-frame-same-audio.html